# How to serialize current div by using $(this).parent() with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to serialize the current div by using a clickevent. See code for good explanation:

```
$("#createreview").live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).parent().serialize());
    $.post('/admin/home/review/create/', $(this).parent().serialize(), function(data){
       alert('Review successfully added to database.' +data);
    });
});
```

Alert will show nothing, which means the div is not being serialized. This is the html in question. It's inside a dialog, which is also the reason why I have to use `live()`.

```
<div id="reviewdiv">
            <input type="hidden" value="7" name="homeid">
            <label>Content</label><textarea name="reviewcontent" id="reviews" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea><br>
            <label>Author</label> <input type="text" name="reviewauthor"><button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="createreview">Save Review</button><button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="removereview">Remove Review</button><br>
        </div>
```

Also this code is working without a problem to remove the current div by using the clickevent and parent selector.

```
$("#removereview").live('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: `data` is going to be the response from the post to the server - not necessarily the data that was serialized. What does your request and response look like when you view it in Firebug - are they what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialize a `<div>`.

The [serialize](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/#serialize) uses internally the [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method. So to serialize input elements that do not belong to a form, use the `param` method. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DdVqJ/

But remember, the correct (and semantic) way is to put your input elements inside a form.

Answer (score 4):

You can't serialize a `<div>`, you need to have a `<form>`, so replace this:

```
<div id="reviewdiv">
```

With this:

```
<form id="reviewdiv">
```

Then you can use this to serialize:

```
$(this).closest('form').serialize()
```

To see the difference [here's what you have](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C56KJ/) (a `<div>`) which *doesn't* serialize and   [here's the `<form>` version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C56KJ/1) which *does* serialize.  Because it uses the [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) collection to loop through, nothing but a `<form>` works here.

Comment: Works thanks! Btw that's a really good website to test things.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but you could just use:

```
$('#reviewdiv :input').serialize();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Sometimes we don't want to serialize an entire form, and simply replacing the div with a form is not a solution if that div is inside another form.